# Providing IP address for a site in iis 7.5

Tags: iis-7.5

I have deployed a website in iis 7.5 
It works with in the same machine when i type the URL : http://localhost/pages/default.asp

Now i want to access this site from another machine...so how do i bind the ip address ?

Comment: Where did you deploy the site? In the Default Web Site, a new website?

Answer (score 1):

In the IIS management console, right click on the site and select Edit Bindings. You can set the port, host header, and IP there and also select an SSL cert if you need to for https bindings.